# nlohmann json reading from file

Tags: c++, json, ifstream

I'm currently reading in my file in this manner:

```
using json = nlohmann::json;

std::ifstream jsonConfigFileStream("/path/to/file.json", std::ifstream::in);
json jsonConfigRoot;

if (jsonConfigFileStream.is_open()) {
  jsonConfigFileStream >> jsonConfigRoot;
}
```

However it keeps giving me the error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument
Abort trap: 6
```

The error should be from the code `jsonConfigFileStream >> jsonConfigRoot`

Anyone can enlighten me on what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly there's error in JSON file. Check correctness in some linter. Also nlohmann json parser don't  like dangling separators like

```
{"node":[1,2,3,4,]}
                ^
```

other fail case - missing quotes for anything except numbers.

wrap it in `try...catch` and log runtime error - in most cases its really explains why parsing failed

if this conditions are fine, then check is it possible to read file at all. log content to stdout or kinda.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Seems like there really was an error in the JSON file and not the code. There is a misplaced quote "

Comment: With version 3.0.0, there will be a more detailed exception message which includes the byte offset of the error.

Comment: @NielsLohmann is there any roadmap? didn't found any link with plans.

Comment: So far, there is a release milestone (https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22Release+3.0.0%22) - in particular https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/301 describes the feature with the byte offset.